# How to convert List<Category> to tree like structure using java 8?

Tags: java, stream

I would like to convert `List<Menu>` to `List<MenuTree>` with childMenus within the `MenuTree` object. How can I achieve this using java 8 streams?

```
public class Menu {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long parentId;
}

public class MenuTree {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private List<MenuTree> childMenus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `MenuTree` for each `Menu`. Store them all in a `Map<Long, MenuTree>` where the key is the ID of the `MenuTree`.

Then iterate and for each `MenuTree`, find its parent by ID in the map, and add it to the children of its parent.

Then find all the `MenuTree` which don't have a `parentId` and put them in a List. That's your result.